# fs.readFile return Buffer object and toString will make terminal complain

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read the content of a PDF and a DOCX, like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('example.pdf, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    process.exit(0);
  }

  console.log(data);
});
```

I searched and i discover that i should stringify the data with toString, right? But if i try to do the terminal will start to make a noise and the data will be like this:

```
<</CreationDate(D:20090121145808Z)/Author(Mauro Mangas)/Creator(Adobe Illustrator\(R\) 13.0)/Producer(Acr0000000000 65535 f.0 \(Macintosh\))/ModDate(D:20090121145808Z)/Title(pdf_janela)>>
0000006390 00000 n
0000006424 00000 n
0000006457 00000 n
0000006508 00000 n
0000010155 00000 n
%EOFtxref>>
```

am i forgetting something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to interpret a pdf file as text, which probably doesn't make much sense.  Some of the characters that end up being printed are control characters, which can tell the terminal to do things like changing the text color or background color, making noise ("bell" character), etc.

Comment: Get it. And how should i get only the text? Is possible? I know that there is packages ready to go, but i want understand how to do, i want learn how to do.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari You need to know how a pdf file is set up.  Probably best off using a library, otherwise it will take a lot of research